# avd manager won't start virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I just installed the sdk.  I created a virtual device in avd manager, and it saved it in d:\userdata\admisistrator.android\avd.  However when  I try to start the virtual device, I get the error  "PANIC: Could not open: D:\Userdata\username.android/avd/droid2.in"

For some reason it saves the virtual devices in the admin area, but tries to run them from my

Comment: How to start the virtual device?

Comment: What's your OS? Is it Windows? Can you please post the error details?